# Script to Find Certain words and delete those lines in a file

Tags: script, wildcards, findstr

**EDITED THE QUESTION as i am open to different type of solutions unlike just batch previously**
I am on Windows & some suggested SED etc. So i am OK with these 3rd party standalone exe's using command line

**Say i have following lines in abc.txt file**

```
"@yuy007 what are you doing friend #disneyrocks"
"STFU, i dont care what you think @happy55"
"@social88 @gg99 ok mate see you at the subway :)"
"btw arnold was great in that movie @tt11 @gg11 #disneyrocks"
"we are going to disney. Do you want to? #disneyrocks"
"We dont like disney. #disneyrocks we are not going" 
".@socialguy what are you upto #disneyrocks "
```

**I need to employ 5 filters with above file to get def.txt**

1. Delete all lines which start with @ character, like 1st and 3rd
2. Delete all lines which start with .@ characters, like 7th
3. Delete all lines which don't have  any word starting with # like 2nd and 3rd
4. In leftover lines, Delete all words starting with @ character (keeping the lines intact) like words @happy55 in 2nd , @social99 & @gg99 in 3rd, etc. **In this case we still need to preserve quotes " at start and end of line**
5. Delete all the blank lines left after above lines are removed

**EDIT**
if i have  following line , it wrongly deletes the content after @word's

```
"btw arnold was great in that movie @tt101 @gb1997 #whatthehell"
```

is edited to

```
"btw arnold was great in that movie"
```

Thanks

Comment: Try that to delete all lines starting with @ - here.  `for /f "delims=" %f in (ab.txt) do @(set a=%f && IF NOT "!a:~0,1!"
=="@" ECHO !a!)`   And for words starting with @  hmm not sure off hand.

Comment: Thanks for replying but i solved this with help of Krowe's answer. I was already using REPL.bat (it works with native batch) so it helped. Please check our chat. i posted some queries. Thanks

Comment: Time to consider unix tools like `grep` and `sed` (which can be installed in Windows too)

Comment: @LatinSuD sir how to do install them in windows and will you help me with commands for above? i will go ahead then

Comment: If you want to use GNU tools for this here is a good place to start: http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ the easy way is to get the automated tool (highly recommended). This is a wonderful thing to have and it is what I would normally use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use regular expressions for this. Because you've specified BATCH as your preferred scripting language we'll need to add that functionality. There are several ways we could accomplish this but I like [this version](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855) written by someone named Dave Benham at dostips.com because it uses only binaries which should already be on your machine:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Documentation ***********
::REPL.BAT version 4.1
:::
:::REPL  Search  Replace  [Options  [SourceVar]]
:::REPL  /?[REGEX|REPLACE]
:::REPL  /V
:::
:::  Performs a global regular expression search and replace operation on
:::  each line of input from stdin and prints the result to stdout.
:::
:::  Each parameter may be optionally enclosed by double quotes. The double
:::  quotes are not considered part of the argument. The quotes are required
:::  if the parameter contains a batch token delimiter like space, tab, comma,
:::  semicolon. The quotes should also be used if the argument contains a
:::  batch special character like &, |, etc. so that the special character
:::  does not need to be escaped with ^.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /?, then prints help documentation
:::  to stdout. If a single argument of /?REGEX, then opens up Microsoft's
:::  JScript regular expression documentation within your browser. If a single
:::  argument of /?REPLACE, then opens up Microsoft's JScript REPLACE
:::  documentation within your browser.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /V, case insensitive, then prints
:::  the version of REPL.BAT.
:::
:::  Search  - By default, this is a case sensitive JScript (ECMA) regular
:::            expression expressed as a string.
:::
:::            JScript regex syntax documentation is available at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Replace - By default, this is the string to be used as a replacement for
:::            each found search expression. Full support is provided for
:::            substituion patterns available to the JScript replace method.
:::
:::            For example, $& represents the portion of the source that matched
:::            the entire search pattern, $1 represents the first captured
:::            submatch, $2 the second captured submatch, etc. A $ literal
:::            can be escaped as $$.
:::
:::            An empty replacement string must be represented as "".
:::
:::            Replace substitution pattern syntax is fully documented at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/efy6s3e6(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Options - An optional string of characters used to alter the behavior
:::            of REPL. The option characters are case insensitive, and may
:::            appear in any order.
:::
:::            I - Makes the search case-insensitive.
:::
:::            L - The Search is treated as a string literal instead of a
:::                regular expression. Also, all $ found in Replace are
:::                treated as $ literals.
:::
:::            B - The Search must match the beginning of a line.
:::                Mostly used with literal searches.
:::
:::            E - The Search must match the end of a line.
:::                Mostly used with literal searches.
:::
:::            V - Search and Replace represent the name of environment
:::                variables that contain the respective values. An undefined
:::                variable is treated as an empty string.
:::
:::            A - Only print altered lines. Unaltered lines are discarded.
:::                If both the M and V options are present, then prints the
:::                entire result if there was a change anywhere in the string.
:::                The A option is incompatible with the M option unless the S
:::                option is also present.
:::
:::            M - Multi-line mode. The entire contents of stdin is read and
:::                processed in one pass instead of line by line, thus enabling
:::                search for \n. This also enables preservation of the original
:::                line terminators. If the M option is not present, then every
:::                printed line is termiated with carriage return and line feed.
:::                The M option is incompatible with the A option unless the S
:::                option is also present.
:::
:::                Note: If working with binary data containing NULL bytes,
:::                      then the M option must be used.
:::
:::            X - Enables extended substitution pattern syntax with support
:::                for the following escape sequences within the Replace string:
:::
:::                \\     -  Backslash
:::                \b     -  Backspace
:::                \f     -  Formfeed
:::                \n     -  Newline
:::                \q     -  Quote
:::                \r     -  Carriage Return
:::                \t     -  Horizontal Tab
:::                \v     -  Vertical Tab
:::                \xnn   -  Extended ASCII byte code expressed as 2 hex digits
:::                \unnnn -  Unicode character expressed as 4 hex digits
:::
:::                Also enables the \q escape sequence for the Search string.
:::                The other escape sequences are already standard for a regular
:::                expression Search string.
:::
:::                Also modifies the behavior of \xnn in the Search string to work
:::                properly with extended ASCII byte codes.
:::
:::                Extended escape sequences are supported even when the L option
:::                is used. Both Search and Replace support all of the extended
:::                escape sequences if both the X and L opions are combined.
:::
:::            S - The source is read from an environment variable instead of
:::                from stdin. The name of the source environment variable is
:::                specified in the next argument after the option string. Without
:::                the M option, ^ anchors the beginning of the string, and $ the
:::                end of the string. With the M option, ^ anchors the beginning
:::                of a line, and $ the end of a line.
:::
::: REPL.BAT was written by Dave Benham, with assistance from DosTips user Aacini
::: to get \xnn to work properly with extended ASCII byte codes. Also assistance
::: from DosTips user penpen diagnosing issues reading NULL bytes, along with a
::: workaround. REPL.BAT was originally posted at:
::: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
if .%2 equ . (
  if "%~1" equ "/?" (
    <"%~f0" cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "^:::" "" a
    exit /b 0
  ) else if /i "%~1" equ "/?regex" (
    explorer "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx"
    exit /b 0
  ) else if /i "%~1" equ "/?replace" (
    explorer "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/efy6s3e6(v=vs.80).aspx"
    exit /b 0
  ) else if /i "%~1" equ "/V" (
    <"%~f0" cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "^::(REPL\.BAT version)" "$1" a
    exit /b 0
  ) else (
    call :err "Insufficient arguments"
    exit /b 1
  )
)
echo(%~3|findstr /i "[^SMILEBVXA]" >nul && (
  call :err "Invalid option(s)"
  exit /b 1
)
echo(%~3|findstr /i "M"|findstr /i "A"|findstr /vi "S" >nul && (
  call :err "Incompatible options"
  exit /b 1
)
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b 0

:err
>&2 echo ERROR: %~1. Use REPL /? to get help.
exit /b

************* JScript portion **********/
var env=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var search=args.Item(0);
var replace=args.Item(1);
var options="g";
if (args.length>2) options+=args.Item(2).toLowerCase();
var multi=(options.indexOf("m")>=0);
var alterations=(options.indexOf("a")>=0);
if (alterations) options=options.replace(/a/g,"");
var srcVar=(options.indexOf("s")>=0);
if (srcVar) options=options.replace(/s/g,"");
if (options.indexOf("v")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/v/g,"");
  search=env(search);
  replace=env(replace);
}
if (options.indexOf("x")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/x/g,"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\q/g,"\"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x80/g,"\\u20AC");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x82/g,"\\u201A");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x83/g,"\\u0192");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x84/g,"\\u201E");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x85/g,"\\u2026");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x86/g,"\\u2020");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x87/g,"\\u2021");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x88/g,"\\u02C6");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x89/g,"\\u2030");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[aA]/g,"\\u0160");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[bB]/g,"\\u2039");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[cC]/g,"\\u0152");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[eE]/g,"\\u017D");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x91/g,"\\u2018");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x92/g,"\\u2019");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x93/g,"\\u201C");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x94/g,"\\u201D");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x95/g,"\\u2022");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x96/g,"\\u2013");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x97/g,"\\u2014");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x98/g,"\\u02DC");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x99/g,"\\u2122");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[aA]/g,"\\u0161");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[bB]/g,"\\u203A");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[cC]/g,"\\u0153");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[dD]/g,"\\u009D");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[eE]/g,"\\u017E");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[fF]/g,"\\u0178");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
    function($0,$1,$2){
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
    }
  );
  replace=replace.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
  search=search.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  search=search.replace(/\\q/g,"\"");
  search=search.replace(/\\x80/g,"\\u20AC");
  search=search.replace(/\\x82/g,"\\u201A");
  search=search.replace(/\\x83/g,"\\u0192");
  search=search.replace(/\\x84/g,"\\u201E");
  search=search.replace(/\\x85/g,"\\u2026");
  search=search.replace(/\\x86/g,"\\u2020");
  search=search.replace(/\\x87/g,"\\u2021");
  search=search.replace(/\\x88/g,"\\u02C6");
  search=search.replace(/\\x89/g,"\\u2030");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[aA]/g,"\\u0160");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[bB]/g,"\\u2039");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[cC]/g,"\\u0152");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[eE]/g,"\\u017D");
  search=search.replace(/\\x91/g,"\\u2018");
  search=search.replace(/\\x92/g,"\\u2019");
  search=search.replace(/\\x93/g,"\\u201C");
  search=search.replace(/\\x94/g,"\\u201D");
  search=search.replace(/\\x95/g,"\\u2022");
  search=search.replace(/\\x96/g,"\\u2013");
  search=search.replace(/\\x97/g,"\\u2014");
  search=search.replace(/\\x98/g,"\\u02DC");
  search=search.replace(/\\x99/g,"\\u2122");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[aA]/g,"\\u0161");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[bB]/g,"\\u203A");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[cC]/g,"\\u0153");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[dD]/g,"\\u009D");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[eE]/g,"\\u017E");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[fF]/g,"\\u0178");
  if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
    search=search.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
    search=search.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
    search=search.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
    search=search.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
    search=search.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
    search=search.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
    search=search.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
      function($0,$1,$2){
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
      }
    );
    search=search.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
  } else search=search.replace(/\\B/g,"\\\\");
}
if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/l/g,"");
  search=search.replace(/([.^$*+?()[{\\|])/g,"\\$1");
  replace=replace.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$");
}
if (options.indexOf("b")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/b/g,"");
  search="^"+search
}
if (options.indexOf("e")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/e/g,"");
  search=search+"$"
}
var search=new RegExp(search,options);
var str1, str2;

if (srcVar) {
  str1=env(args.Item(3));
  str2=str1.replace(search,replace);
  if (!alterations || str1!=str2) if (multi) {
    WScript.Stdout.Write(str2);
  } else {
    WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(str2);
  }
} else if (multi){
  var buf=1024;
  str1="";
  while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
    str1+=WScript.StdIn.Read(buf);
    buf*=2
  }
  WScript.Stdout.Write(str1.replace(search,replace));
} else {
  while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
    str1=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
    str2=str1.replace(search,replace);
    if (!alterations || str1!=str2) WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(str2);
  }
}
```

Copy that and save it as *repl.bat*. You may want to place it in your system path if you think you'll use it again. Otherwise just put it with the files you are working on. Now create another file for this task (I called it *test.bat*):

```
@echo off
type abc.txt | repl "^[\s\q]@[^\s].*\r?\n?" "" XM | repl "[\s\q]@[^\s\q]+" "" X > abc.out.txt
```

That should give you what you want. This has been modified to output Windows line endings (my text editor doesn't care so I didn't notice the problem).

- The `repl "^[\s\q]@[^\s].*\r?\n?" "" XM` part of this removes every line which begins with a quote or a @. It will ignore lines which just have `"@ some text` or `@ some text` or just `@` or `"@` (the @ must be followed by at least one non whitespace character). You may remove this requirement by removing the `[^\s]`.
- The `repl "[\s\q]@[^\s\q]+" "" X` part of this removes every word which begins with a @ and has at least one character which is not whitespace or a quote after it.

We use the X parameter because it adds the /q replacement which allows us to search for those pesky quotes. The M option is needed so that we can actually replace new lines (also, without it we'd have an extra blank line at the end). Further information can be found in the [JScript RegEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx) reference.

**Note:** I've now fixed some issues with the above replacements and made them much simpler using better commands for this.

---

If you want to show only lines which contain a @ then you can use:

```
type abc.txt | repl "^((?![\q\s]@\w+).)*$" "" X | repl "\r?\n?\s*$" "" M > abc.out2.txt
```

This one took a long time to figure out how to get to work in all situations and I may have missed a few possible combinations. It will ignore email addresses and @ character by themselves in a line though. RegEx isn't great at negating results and requires the use of a look-ahead to do this. The second part of this deals with part of that mess by removing all blank lines left over after the first call. This has the possibly unwanted side-effect of also removing any already blank lines in the file.

Comment: Thanks Krowe for reply. yes i am already using Repl.bat (i had another question which got solved using it). But i REQUEST you to explain me how you made up that command "repl "\n?\r?\q@.+\n" "\n" XM | repl " @.+? " " " XM | repl " @.+?\q" "\q" XM "  i want to understand the basics/breakup of that so that in future i can do it myself for some other pattern i would like to edit/replace

Comment: I just used it & there is a small issue. After using, in output file, there is a box like character (like seen when we try to edit a encrypted exe) as 1st letter of 1st line. Rest all lines appear fine. Thanks

Comment: can you read me @Krowe ?

Comment: 1)plz explain me to how to make such commands 2) kindly look into error issue 3) what command should be used if i instead only want those lines, which have got at least 1 word (anywhere in line) starting with @ ?

Comment: @SuperUserMan I've updated to answer all of these questions and it proper Windows line endings.

Comment: RegEx is a VERY complex topic. I suggest you begin reading up on them by visiting http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html . The only way to get good at it is to do it over and over and over and even then it is often confusing.

Comment: BTW, I was not being notified of your posts. I just found out that is probably because they are doing maintainance on the site: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8366/stackexchange-notifications-wont-clear-even-after-they-are-read

Comment: Looks like notifications till not fixed. Thanks a lot for reply.i understood more (but understanding regex seems remote :( ). If i may ask another thing, If i want to trim all text/content between quotes(excluding quotes as they are important) in each line, to <=10 characters from start, can it be done with this replace script or there is any better way? Please if possible explain your command. Regards . P.S. My emphasis is always on  learning things so that i dont to ask questions again

Comment: i got this link for something similar.. but not understand much ..can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760911/batch-file-that-trims-leading-characters-and-lets-me-save-where-i-want

Comment: There are easier ways to do that. Which one you use depends on which version of Windows you're targeting. This site explains what you'll want: http://www.fpschultze.de/modules/smartfaq/faq.php?faqid=20

Comment: Sorry but Krowe there is a problem. When there is word at the end of line following "at the rate of" , probably the 3rd repl command is also removing that. I added the issue in main question .One more query Krowe. Just like we removed words starting with "at the rate of", how to also remove words which start with .@   ?Thanks

Comment: @SuperUserMan I believe I've fixed the problem for you. If not, it is because I'm having trouble understanding what you want.

Comment: i am still having issues. I have overhauled the question as in a separate similar question, i was asked to edit this question itself. Please have a look and sort things pointwise so that i can understand what command is doing what.Thanks

Comment: there is also this program rxrepl http://superuser.com/questions/339118/regex-replace-from-command-line/540669#comment1474545_540669